# In HTML5 should I use article or section tags to make tabs?

Tags: css, html

I want to create a set of content tabs for a design I'm building in HTML5.  I'm wondering if I should use a set of `<article>` or `<section>` tags to contain the content?

Comment: hmmm, still not sure myself how to REALLY use `<section>` especially from an SEO Point of View since every section is supposed to have its own heading-space and at least I'm not really sure how google sees that atm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`<section>` seems ideal to me. Its [definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-section-element) applies quite neatly to something like content tabs:

> The section element represents a generic section of a document or application. A section, in this context, is a thematic grouping of content, typically with a heading.
>
> Examples of sections would be chapters, the various tabbed pages in a tabbed dialog box, or the numbered sections of a thesis. A Web site's home page could be split into sections for an introduction, news items, and contact information.

Take note of what it says about `<article>` on that same page though:

> Authors are encouraged to use the article element instead of the section element when it would make sense to syndicate the contents of the element.

So if the content of your tabs is self-contained and makes sense when read in isolation (and could be used that way), use `<article>`, if it doesn't use `<section>`.

Comment: My tabs definitely act more like sections than individual articles, so I used sections.

Comment: If you look further down the [definition](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/sections.html#the-section-element), you'll see a sample use case for using `<section>` includes "the various tabbed pages in a tabbed dialog box".

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that `<section>` elements are supposed to go inside `<article>` elements, so you shouldn't use `sections` for tabs unless you wrap all of the tabs inside of an article. So the short answer is you should use both or neither.

Comment: 99.9% sure that articles are supposed to go inside sections, at least I don't think sections are meant to go inside articles.

Comment: @jonezy Either way is allowed - an article can have multiple sections, a section can have multiple articles

Comment: ya i actually just went and looked it up, interesting.